# Is there a way I can repeatedly display a user_input question in the console, after entering a response?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, visual-studio-code, input

[image: Code]

How, after creating a user_input question and when inputting a response to the console, can I get the question to ask again, without having to run the script again?

Would I use a for/while loop for this? I have had a look around and tested some stuff out but I get errors or it doesn't work at all. I'm fairly new to programming. Thank you!

Comment: Look into while loops, with a termination condition of some sort.

Comment: you would use a while loop. While the answer is not acceptable, keep asking teh question until there is an acceptable answer. Its also useful to give an escape option for the user to quite

Comment: In that image, the final `elif` is never reached because the category `>= 18` subsumes the `>= 60`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should use a while loop for this.

Keep in mind that to learn programming, you have to move forward one *small* step at a time, especially in the beginnings.

So if you want to use a while loop, learn to use it separately in another tutorial. Only when you're confortable with 'while' and 'input / print', try to combine both.

If you keep this mentality for everything during your learning, you should grow fast !

Good luck !